# What possible penalties can there be for failing to comply with rule 286 of the UK highway code?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, driving, motor-vehicle, accident

Rule 286 requires one to give one's name and address to another party in the case of an accident, but what is the penalty range for non compliance?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Rule 286](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/breakdowns-and-incidents-274-to-287#:%7E:text=Rule%20286,-If%20you%20are&text=if%20you%20do%20not%20give,any%20case%20within%2024%20hours.) states:

> If you are involved in a collision which causes damage or injury to any other person, vehicle, animal or property, you **MUST**
>
> - stop. If possible, stop in a place of relative safety (see Rule 275)
> - give your own and the vehicle owner’s name and address, and the registration number of the vehicle, to anyone having reasonable grounds for requiring them
> - if you do not give your name and address at the time of the collision, report it to the police as soon as reasonably practicable, and in any case within 24 hours.

This mirrors the underlying legislation at [section 170](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/52/section/170?timeline=false) of the Road Traffic Act 1988:

> (2) The driver of the mechanically propelled vehicle must stop and, if required to do so by any person having reasonable grounds for so requiring, give his name and address and also the name and address of the owner and the identification marks of the vehicle.
>
> (3) If for any reason the driver of the mechanically propelled vehicle does not give his name and address under subsection (2) above, he must report the accident.
>
> **(4) A person who fails to comply with subsection (2) or (3) above is guilty of an offence.**

The penalty for this offence depends on the particular circumstances, and, as per  the [Sentencing Council](https://www.sentencingcouncil.org.uk/offences/magistrates-court/item/fail-to-stopreport-road-accident-revised-2017/)' guidelines, it is:

> Triable only summarily:
>
> Maximum: Unlimited fine and/or 6 months
>
> Offence range: Band A fine – 26 weeks’ custody

A Band A fine is:

> 25 – 75% of relevant weekly income

The Offence Range has three Categories to determine the appropriate sentence depending on the:

> Level of seriousness

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136237/discussion-on-answer-by-rick-what-possible-penalties-can-there-be-for-failing-to).

Answer (score 8):

In the event that one (or more) of the following applies:

- Personal Injury, or
- Damage to a Vehicle, or
- Damage or Injury to an Animal
- Damage to Property attached to the road where the accident occurred

the driver of a vehicle is required to stop their vehicle and provide his / her name, address, the details of the vehicle owner and the vehicle registration to a person that has reasonable grounds to require this information from the driver. Or, failing that report the accident to the police within 24 hours.

Failure to do so constitutes a "failure to stop" and is an offence under [S.170 of the Road Traffic Act 1988](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/52/section/170)

Penalties vary depending upon circumstances but include:

- 5 to 10 Penalty Points
- Driving ban of up to 12 months
- Prison Sentence of up to 6 months
- Community Order
- Fine of an unlimited amount

Full sentencing guidelines can (and the various factors affecting severity) can be found [here](https://www.sentencingcouncil.org.uk/offences/magistrates-court/item/fail-to-stopreport-road-accident-revised-2017/)