# How is an animal defined as in rule 286 of the UK highway code?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-terms, definition

This  came up in the comments thread of [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/80059/35069) so it was suggested to ask it.

Is a fly an animal? Perhaps it must be one that is kept and thus keepable as chattel?

Comment: Didn't you see my quote of the statute in a later comment there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Is a fly an animal?**

Not in the context of the [Highway Code Rule 286](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/breakdowns-and-incidents-274-to-287#:%7E:text=Rule%20286,-If%20you%20are&text=if%20you%20do%20not%20give,any%20case%20within%2024%20hours.), as the underlying legislation at [section 170](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/52/section/170?timeline=false) of the Road Traffic Act 1988 states:

> (8) In this section “animal” means horse, cattle, ass, mule, sheep, pig, goat or dog.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136236/discussion-on-answer-by-rick-how-is-an-animal-defined-as-in-rule-286-of-the-uk-h).